# Can I manually create the confusion matrix y_true array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

I dont know how to get y_true from customdatagenerator

Can I direct creat a array and input label data?

```
val_datagen = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, valid_dir, **params, shuffle = False)

Y_pred = model.predict(val_datagen)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1) 
y_true = np.array([0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,   
                   1,1,1,1,1, 1,
                   2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,
                   3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,
                   4,4,4,4,
                   5,5,5,5,5, 5,5,5,5,5,
                   6,6,6,6,])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))  
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred),annot=True, fmt="d", cmap='Greens',ax = ax)
```

In val_dataset I have 12 * label0, 6 * label1, 7 * label2.....

And "shuffle = False" ensure that y_true can perfect correspond y_pred

Comment: You have asked the same question over and over, multiple times, that is not allowed, ask questions exactly once.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think this time my question is different, I ask manually create y_true, not get y_true from Customdatagenerator

Comment: No, they are all about y_true from a generator. And I already answered the same issue (very common actually) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367878/is-the-classes-method-of-a-imagedatagenorator-sorted/74411647#74411647