# Different accuracy when using model.evaluate() and model.predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm performing multi-class classification with 4 labels, I have different result when using model.predict() and model.evaluate(), here my code:

```
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(testing_generator)
```

the result from this code is
Test Loss: 0.0561
Test Accuracy: 99.31%

```
y_true = testing_generator.classes
y_pred_probs = model.predict(testing_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred_probs, axis=1)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

the result from this code is
Accuracy: 25.17%

I use the same testing_generator which contain testing images, why this can be happen? anyone know how to solve it?

I'm stuck in this problem, I expect the accuracy to be the same value because I'm using the same testing_generator

Comment: Please check the old questions, this has been asked too many times. 
The order of labels provided by testing_generator.classes does not match the order of the output from model.predict. Testing generator is shuffling your data.

Comment: @Frightera should i turn off shuffle on testing_generator?

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367878/is-the-classes-method-of-a-imagedatagenorator-sorted/74411647#74411647